# One-hot-encoded labels___multi-hot-encoded output_Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding, multiclass-classification

I have a 1D-image with 1x2048 pixels as input and 32 classes for which I have defined a layer of 32 filters with the same size of the image(1x2048) which are L1-regularized.

My image examples are one-hot encodded. However, my goal is to get a multi-hot encoded output when I sum some of these images together and feed it to the trained model.

The training goes well and it can classify each class seperately, but if I sum two image and feed it to the model it only outputs a one-hot encoded vector( although I expect a two-hot encoded vector). If I look at the kernels after training, they make sense as most of the weights are zero except the ones which define my class.

I don't understand why I get a one-hot vector output rather than multi-hot vector.

The reason I don't already sum the images and use them for training the model is that the possible making the possible combination of the images exceed my memory power.

[An image of the network I have in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hB6h.png)

```
input_shape=(1,2048,1)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1, 2048), strides=(1, 1),
activation='sigmoid', 
input_shape=input_shape,
kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),
kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.non_neg()            ))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,     
optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You are using the wrong loss function

`categorical_crossentropy` will always return you exactly *one* 1-value in your vector, no matter the input. It tries to classify every instance into one (and only one) available class.

What you desire, though, is (potentially) mutliple ones in your output. Therefore, you should use [`binary_crossentropy`](https://keras.io/losses/#binary_crossentropy) instead. Also see [this post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2166).

On a side note, I would heavily advice you to really consider this twice, since - if you don't really have the case with multiple classes that often, it will maybe result in a lot of false positives. I.e., cases where you get more than one class predicted.

On another note, you might want to consider using `Conv1D` since your signal is 1-dimensional only.

Answer (score 0):

@Azerila
The thing you are looking for is Mixup augmentation. It is implemented as follows:

```py
def mixup(entry1,entry2):
    image1,label1 = entry1
    image2,label2 = entry2
    
    alpha = [0.2]
    dist = tfd.Beta(alpha, alpha)
    l = dist.sample(1)[0][0]
    
    img = l*image1+(1-l)*image2
    lab = l*label1+(1-l)*label2
    
    return img, lab
```